# Efficient indexing and retrieve data from a large data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very big data frame, with millions of rows. The data frame looks like:

```
id  value ......
111  1  
222  4
111  5
333  6
222  8
444  9
555  4
222  2
111  4
```

Every time, I want to retrieve a particular id, with all of the values. If I simply use

```
df[df$id == myid,]
```

It could be very costly, as the data frame will scan all of the ids in the table.

Is there any methods to index data frame?

Comment: See the `data.table` package which allows keying columns. In `base` R, you can order your data frame through `df<-df[order(df$id),]` then get the indices of the first occurrence of each `id` with `match(unique(df$id),df$id)`. Once you got the indices, you can subset very efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data.table` package is designed to work with exactly this sort of situation.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
setkey(dt, id) # index the data.table by the id column

dt[myid] # extract the id==myid row
```

You can perform operations by reference (rather than by value) and have extremely little overhead.